# jquery (hover and load) events binding on dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to bind `click` event to element with class name `keybox`. And this element is generated dynamically.

```
$('body').on('click','.keybox', function(){
// some code here
});
```

But for same element I tried binding `hover` and `load` event using following code:

```
$('body').on('hover','.keybox', function(){
// some code here
});


$('body').on('load','.keybox', function(){
// some code here
});
```

....and its not working as expected.

Can someone help with this problem? I want to bind `hover` and `load` event to my element with class name `keybox` and this element is generated dynamically.

Comment: you need to make sure that the element is already present from the DOM before binding the event handlers, how are you executing your binding method?

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: my JS file is a content script inside a chrome extension. Its loaded after the actual page load. i.e.,  `body` is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hover, use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event. Instead of body.load use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following approach to bind multiple events and get object information via [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

```
$('body').bind('click hover load', '.keybox', function(e){
   if ( e.type === 'hover') {
     // do something
   }
   else if(e.type === 'click') {
    // do something
   }
   ....
});
```

Make sure you bind events in `$(document).ready(function() {}` or load javascript just in bottom of `html` document body.

Answer (score 0):

Since `hover` is deprecated you should use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` for `load` you can write using event using `on`(`load` is equivalent to `ready`).

```js
$(function(){
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.keybox', function () {
            $(this).css('color','red');
    });
   $(document).on('mouseleave', '.keybox', function () {
            $(this).css('color','black');
    });
   $(document).on('click', '.keybox', function () {// click on dynamically loaded events.
            $(this).css('color','green');
    });
    $('#btn').click(function() {
         
         $('#parent').append("<div class='keybox'>sample1</div>");
         $('#parent').append("<div class='keybox'>sample2</div>"); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
   zdhsdhsau 
</div>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="create"/>
```